# For an at-grade intersection of multi-lane roads, what are the (dis)advantages of a "turborotonde" or "turboplein" compared to a classical roundabout?

Tags: highway-engineering

For an at-grade intersection of multi-lane roads, the "Turborotonde" ([Dutch language Wikipedia article](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turborotonde)) or "Turboplein" ([Dutch language wegenwiki article](https://www.wegenwiki.nl/Turboplein)) is an alternative to the multi-lane roundabout:

[image: Turborotonde]
*Source: [Juerd, Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Turborotonde.svg)*

Or the larger turboplein:

[image: Turboplein] 
*Source: [Rijkswaterstaat / Joop van Houdt, via wegenwiki](https://www.wegenwiki.nl/Bestand:Turboplein_N213.jpg)*

Compared to a classic multi-lane roundabout:

[image: Roundabout]
*Source: [Ferdrik, Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NonUK_Roundabout_8_Cars.gif)*

For an at-grade intersection of multi-lane roads, what are the (dis)advantages of a "turborotonde" compared to a classical roundabout?  It would appear that the turborotonde should be safer, but it may be that there are disadvantages too.  For example, it appears not (legally) possible to turn around (full circle).  What are other disadvantages compared to a classic roundabout?

See also: *[Are there any turborotonde / turboplein designs with more than four exits?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/22627/3599)*

Comment: I have never seen a turborotonde until now, but from looking at it you are correct, vehicles cannot use it to do a U-turn. The other thing is that a turborotonde separates streams of traffic, which is a safety feature, but they all require drivers to be aware were they are going & to commit to particular lanes of when negotiating the turborotonde.

Answer (score 1):

For a turbo roundabout traffic has to commit to a direction in advance of the intersection. This means having a long approach and adding clear signs above the road.

Depending on where you put it people will be unfamiliar with the concept and do odd maneuvers, creating dangerous situations. Though this is temporary and extra signs can help with that.

You can add a U-turn path should the flow be big enough to require it.