# Are there any turborotonde / turboplein designs with more than four exits?

Tags: highway-engineering

For an at-grade intersection of multi-lane roads, the "Turborotonde" ([Dutch language Wikipedia article](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turborotonde)) or "Turboplein" ([Dutch language wegenwiki article](https://www.wegenwiki.nl/Turboplein)) is an alternative to the multi-lane roundabout:

[image: Turborotonde]
*Source: [Juerd, Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA 4.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Turborotonde.svg)*

Or the larger turboplein:

[image: Turboplein] 
*Source: [Rijkswaterstaat / Joop van Houdt, via wegenwiki](https://www.wegenwiki.nl/Bestand:Turboplein_N213.jpg)*

Both examples have exactly four exits.  In principle, I can imagine that such a design can be extended to more than four exits.  Are there any examples of a *turborotonde* or *turboplein* design with more than four exits?  What would it look like?

*See also: [For an at-grade intersection of multi-lane roads, what are the (dis)advantages of a "turborotonde" or "turboplein" compared to a classical roundabout?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/22626/3599)*

Comment: Try google earth...

Comment: @SolarMike Look at every single at-grade intersection of 5+ roads in the world?  That's a lot of work!  Even when limiting to The Netherlands.

Comment: So why should we? Or are you just hoping people will say "Oh, I live next to one..."

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not suggesting anyone else should.  Perhaps some people with more knowledge on highway engineering than I have happen to know the answer, or know where to find it more easily.  That's why I ask it here.